# DiskcacheManager not working in Dash App in Production. Caching issue?

Tags: python, nginx, plotly-dash, uwsgi

Posting my question from the Plotly forums for greater scope.

---

Good day! This is a continuation of a [previous post](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-app-in-ubuntu-production-under-nginx-and-uwsgi-no-longer-working/71907/2), and despite following the assistance there, and spending countless hours, I've been unable to progress.

I believe it is a **caching** issue that my server is not allowing, but I am uncertain.

Please note - that I am a mere hobbyist, with limited knowledge on servers and the alike. I am simply trying to satiate my curiosities in the wonderful world of Python and Plotly.

### Summary

I have

- A Flask App, served through NGINX and UWSGI

-- Found here: [gusmontano.com](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-app-in-ubuntu-production-under-nginx-and-uwsgi-no-longer-working/71907/2)
-- It is in a Digital Ocean Ubuntu Droplet

- I made a Dash App, that, loosely speaking, is connected to my Flask app.

-- It is a simple 'curiosity project', that converts an YouTube video to an MP3: http://gusmontano.com/p/youtube-to-mp3.

-- The Dash App streams a YouTube video, caches the result into memory, converts to an MP3, before releasing it to the user.

- There are no issues when running this locally in Ubuntu (remotely), through the usual `python run.py`, or UWSGI
- As soon as I kick off NGINX to serve the app - it no longer works.

### Investigation: Running the App in 3 Cases

#### Using `python run.py`

The app works successfully, with the logs showing

```bash
POST /youtube_to_mp3/_dash-update-component?cacheKey=fe28ff0541f35547ba138fd511b0f82446a07aeb&job=2336913 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

#### Using uwsgi

`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5001 --protocol=http -w run:app`

The app runs successfully, with the logs showing

```bash
[pid: 2336956|app: 0|req: 11/11] 99.98.109.223 () {40 vars in 888 bytes} [Sun Jan 29 22:51:14 2023] POST /youtube_to_mp3/_dash-update-component?cacheKey=a36db1c766c643ac5a94d1733982551e3685c69d&job=2336964 => generated 4922432 bytes in 1197 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 76 bytes (12 switches on core 0)
```

#### Introducing NGINX

With NGINX - the app no longer works. The app is kicked-off, but I believe the button callback is never initiated due to problems with caching.

### The Flask App

The Flask App, including the *linking* to the Dash App is shown below.

```py
from flask import Flask

from app.extensions import db, login_manager
from app.blueprints.admin.admin import adm
from app.blueprints.users.view import user
from app.blueprints.auth.auth import auth

import app.models.other_apps.youtube_to_mp3.app as youtube_to_mp3_app

DIGITAL_OCEAN_POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING = 'POSTGRESQL_DETAILS'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = DIGITAL_OCEAN_POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "MY_SECRET_KEY"
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(user)
    app.register_blueprint(adm, url_prefix="/admin")
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/auth")

    # Here comes the Dash app!
    youtube_to_mp3_app.initialise(app)

    return app
```

### The Dash App

The Dash App is shown below. **Please ignore using Redis and Celery**. While I understand the benefits, it requires a greater investment of time to setup Celery. I will read into this. Instead, I am attempting to solve the **Disk Cache** issue in the `else` statement.

In production, I have observed that there are issues completing the steps in the `else` statement. I believe something is wrong in the caching, and I am hoping for assistance here.

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, Input, Output, State, DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pytube import YouTube, exceptions
from uuid import uuid4
from os import environ
from io import BytesIO

from .layout import app_layout

APP_NAME = 'youtube_to_mp3'
APP_STYLESHEET = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@5.2.3/dist/lux/bootstrap.min.css"

launch_uid = uuid4()

def initialise(server):

    if 'REDIS_URL' in environ and False:
        # Use Redis & Celery if REDIS_URL set as an env variable
        from celery import Celery
        celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=environ['REDIS_URL'], backend=environ['REDIS_URL'])
        background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app)

    else:
        # Diskcache for non-production apps when developing locally
        import diskcache
        cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
        background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(cache, cache_by=[lambda: launch_uid], expire=60)

    dash_app = Dash(__name__,
                    server=server,
                    url_base_pathname=f'/{APP_NAME}/',
                    external_stylesheets=[APP_STYLESHEET],
                    background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager
                    )

    dash_app.layout = app_layout

    @dash_app.callback(
        output=Output('downloaded_file', 'data'),
        inputs=Input('button_submit', 'n_clicks'),
        background=True,
        state=State('input_youtube_link', 'value'),
        running=[(Output('button_submit', 'disabled'), 'True', 'False')],
        progress=[Output('status', 'children')],
        prevent_initial_call=True,
        manager=background_callback_manager)
    def update_output(set_progress, n_clicks, youtube_link):
        if n_clicks > 0:
            try:
                # Get YouTube Object
                set_progress('Downloading audio...')
                yt = YouTube(youtube_link)
                # Stream audio only, and download to memory
                audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                audio_bytes = BytesIO()
                audio.stream_to_buffer(audio_bytes)
                audio_bytes.seek(0)
                # Convert audio to MP3 format
                set_progress('Converting audio to MP3 format...')
                sound = AudioSegment.from_file(file=audio_bytes).export(BytesIO(), 'mp3')
                set_progress('Done!')
                return dcc.send_bytes(sound.getvalue(), f'{yt.streams[0].title}.mp3')
            except exceptions.RegexMatchError:
                set_progress('Inappropriate URL. Check and try again.')

    return dash_app
```

### NGINX Conf

My NGINX Configuration is shown below

```bash
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name gusmontano.com www.gusmontano.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/gusmontanocom/gusmontanocom.sock;
        }

}
```

**`nginx.conf`**

```bash
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 3600;

}
```

I truly appreciate any help here, and am using this as a great learning exercise into servers and clients!